# Extended or overriding functionality of the secure function for the Request Class in Laravel's framework, best action?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm currently using Laravel 4 and was wandering how I can override the Request::secure() method, I'm writing an application that will be behind a load balancer as such I'd rather have the function return true if a header value as applied from the load balancer.

How should it ideally be done? I've read this blog post here http://fideloper.com/extend-request-response-laravel that seems a bit over kill.

I Don't totally understand the Facades concept for Laravel? Is it possible that's where in lyes my answer in how to do this?

Comment: That blog post is pretty much the answer to your question. The "Facade" is just like a contract/interface to the Response.

Comment: Didn't you mean `Request::secure()`?

Comment: Yes I did sorry it was a late night typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As fideloper mentioned is his article, extending the `Request` class goes a little bit differently than it goes with normal classes. Simpler, though:

**1.** Create your extended `Request` class and make sure it can be autoloaded;

**ExtendedRequest.php**

```
namespace Raphael\Extensions;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response as IlluminateResponse;

class Response extends IlluminateResponse {
    public function isSecure() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note that we extended the `isSecure` method, instead of `secure`. This is because `secure` simply calls `isScure`, from Symfony's base `Request` class.

**2.** Make sure Laravel uses your extended class. To do so, alter your **start.php** file;

**bootstrap/start.php**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The first thing we will do is create a new Laravel application instance
| which serves as the "glue" for all the components of Laravel, and is
| the IoC container for the system binding all of the various parts.
|
*/

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
Application::requestClass('Raphael\Extensions\Request');

$app = new Application;

$app->redirectIfTrailingSlash();
```

**3.** Make sure you have the right alias set in your **app.php** config file.

**app/config/app.php**

```
'aliases' => array(
    // ...
    'Request' => 'Raphael\Extensions\Request',
    // ...
),
```

Comment: Where should I be putting the class for it to be autoloaded?

Comment: Anywhere, as long as you set it properly on your composer.json. I like to place my files under `app/lib`, without any namespace. Then I simply add `"app/lib"` on my `composer.json` file, under `autload`.`classmap`.